# difference between "opinion" and "input"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What's the difference between "opinion" and "input" (when it's used in the sense of "opinion")? Are there any subtle connotations that a non-native English speaker would not notice and, thus, make a mistake?

Webster does a good job explaining out the subtle hues in meaning between synonyms, but, sadly, for the group of synonyms of "opinion" it didn't include "input":

[image]

Is it like "input" is sort of more technical and more suitable for a discussion, in which more than two people involved? For example, if the text below implies a discussion done by a group of specialists in some area, then "input" would fit better than "opinion":

> He would never interrupt me or change the topic of our discussion and would always wait for me first to address him directly before he could share his own **input** on the subject matter or provide his answer.

or not?

Comment: _Input_ doesn't specifically mean 'opinion', it just means 'something put in - a contribution'. In the context of a discussion, it _can_ mean 'an idea contributed by someone'.

Comment: @KateBunting - Thank you. Does the number of interlocuters involved in discussion matter?

Comment: I would expect to see it used of a group discussion rather than a dialogue between two people. _Input_ does not fit better than _opinion_ in the passage you quoted; either could be used.

Comment: @KateBunting - I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question: Is "input" is sort of more technical and more suitable for a discussion, in which more than two people involved?**

*input* doesn't have to be technical, but as @Kate Bunting commented, it's more suitable in a group discussion, although it can be used in a dialogue as well.

**Question: Webster does a good job explaining out the subtle hues in meaning between synonyms, but, sadly, for the group of synonyms of "opinion" it didn't include "input"**

*opinion* implies the need to **deliberate** on ambiguities, and that's why in the synonym discussion you quoted, *input* is not included.  Instead, *opinion* is compared with other words signaling different ways ambiguities are dealt with in the deliberation: the *subject* doing the deliberation, the *process* of the deliberation, the *result* of the deliberation.

In another sense, *input* is **more general** than *opinion* and can pertain to ideas that do not directly addresses the topic, thus *input* may not include deliberation.  Let's say someone asked me what's the best car on the market.  If I don't want to disclose my opinion (say, Toyota Camry), I can say: "I cannot give you an opinion, but my input is for you to go to edmunds.com."

Or more specifically: "I cannot give you an opinion, but I *recommend* consulting edmunds.com".  In making a sentence we always want to be as specific as possible, so if you can be more specific, *opinion* is better than *input*.

Comment: Very clear now. Thank you!